# How to create Postgres function from Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have a Postgres function, similar as below, which works fine while running from SQL editor. I want to create the same function from Java. How to do it?
Postgres version is 9.1

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION abc()
RETURNS void as
$BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
......
--do something
END;
```

Comment: what has this got to do with javascript?  What function and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Step One - Learn the language you want to write the function in.

Comment: `public void abc () { // do somthing }`

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE FUNCTION` is an SQL statement like all others. You run it with

```
java.sql.Connection conn = ...;
conn.createStatement("CREATE FUNCTION ...").execute;
```

just like every other SQL statement that does not return a result set.